# why is my some of my webpage hiding under my css menu

Tags: html, css

on my website im currently working on i have a css menu with my website logo a text box and a drop down now. i have my login form made with a table like this

```
<p>&nbsp;</p><table width="40%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr> 
<td bgcolor="#d5e8f9" class="mnuheader" >
<div align="center"><font size="5"><strong>Login 
    Members</strong></font></div></td>
</tr>
<tr> 
<td bgcolor="#e5ecf9" class="mnubody"><form name="form1" method="post" action="">
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p align="center">Your Email 
      <input name="email" type="text" id="email">
    </p>
    <p align="center"> Password: 
      <input name="pwd" type="password" id="pwd">
    </p>
    <p align="center"> 
      <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Login">
    </p>
    <p align="center"><a href="register.php">Register</a> | <a href="forgot.php">Forgot</a></p>
  </form></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

this will show up under my css menu or ontop of it in google chrome it shows up on top and in opera it shows up under.. so what im trying to do is make the table and the rest of the webpage appear below the css menu without using the <br / > tags is there any other way?

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TonnaJacob/NYcHN/1/)
 in my jsfiddle i have put html comments for what is what i put my <br /> in a html comment in capital if it will help you find it .. and hopefully this post can help some one else later on

to see what i mean that it goes under/ontop remove the <br /> tags from the html and run the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.titlebar_mblack
{
    margin-top: 61px;

}
```

Your nav bar has a height of 61px, so just give the title bar a margin-top of 61px.
and remove your 5 `<br />`s

http://jsfiddle.net/NYcHN/2/

Comment: if i put the css and remove the breaks will my login table be below the titlebar?

Comment: it should, check the jsfiddle I provided.

Comment: i want my menu to be on each webpage but that will take up to much space to have the code in each file in html how can i get the file contents of menu.html i know i can do it in php but i dont want to because that takes to much time

Comment: I'm sure there's other ways but I only know of two, which is javascript and php, and php would be the most simplest option.

Answer (score 1):

I will add the following line

```
div.titlebar_mblack{
 margin-top:100px;
}
```

This way you don't need to put `<br/>`

If you care for the reason...

```
#cssmenu{
...
position:fixed
...
}
```

Position fixed: The element is position relative to the window.  In other words cssmenu will always be on top.

Hope this helps